# Array Asociativo en el YML de Springboot

Tags: spring-boot

Quiero obtener los datos en el java de un array de clave/valor que estará en el YML

Yml:

```
profiles: 
 - type: user
   url:  www
 - type: admin
   url:  http
```

Lo recojo como:

```
@Value("${profiles}")
private List<Profile> profiles;
```

Y la clase asociada es:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Profile {
    private String type;
    private String url;
}
```

Pero me da error al intentar arrancar:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'api': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'profiles' in value "${profiles}"
```

¿ Qué falla ? Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo resolví:
 Para recogerlos:

```
   @Autowired
   ListRoles profiles;
```

La clase Principal y la subClase:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "available-channels-list")
@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ListRoles {
  List<Profile> profiles;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Profile {
    private String type;
    private String url;
}
```

Faltaba la etiqueta

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "available-channels-list")
@Configuration
```

En el yml

```
available-channels-list:
 profiles: 
  -
    type: "user"
    url:  "www"
  -
    type: "admin"
    url:  "http"
```